# zsh: abort Sorting array

Tags: arrays, c

I'm using this program to sort the numbers in a array, for some reason I get different outputs with the same input, sometimes the output is the expected but some others I get zsh: abort error

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 6

// Functions signature
int *sortNums(int[]);

int main() {

    int *p;
    int a[SIZE] = {6,5,4,3,2,1};
    

    p = sortNums(a);

} // end main

int *sortNums(int a[])
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int temp;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            if (a[j] > a[j+1])
            {
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = temp;
            } // end if
            
        } // end inner for
        
    } // end outer for

    // print numbers in order
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d", a[i]);
    }
    
    return a;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you think `a[j+1]` does in the last iteration of the j-loop?

Comment: I just realized I have to go up to SIZE - 1. Cheers